# How to implement linked singleSelect while using custom component ( renderEditCell ) in MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've implemented linked singleSelect with the following example https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing/#linked-fields

On top of that, I've tried to make it a custom component by changing the renderEditCell as per, https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing/#create-your-own-edit-component

I'm unable to find a way to find the selected option of another component to calculate and change the available options of second component via renderEditCell method.

example code:

```
    {
      field: 'type',
      headerName: 'Type auto',
      type: 'singleSelect',
      editable: true,
      renderEditCell: (params: GridRenderEditCellParams) => {
        const valueOptions = ['Income', 'Expense'] 
        return (
          <Autocomplete
            disablePortal
            options={valueOptions}
            sx={{ width: params.colDef.width }}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Type" />}
          />
        )
      }
    },
 
    {
      field: 'accounta',
      headerName: 'Account auto',
      type: 'singleSelect',
      valueOptions: ({ row }) => {
        if (!row) {
          return [
            'Sales',
            'Investments',
            'Ads',
            'Taxes',
            'Payroll',
            'Utilities',
            'Marketing',
          ];
        }

        return row.type === 'Income'
          ? ['Sales', 'Investments', 'Ads']
          : ['Taxes', 'Payroll', 'Utilities', 'Marketing'];
      },
      editable: true,
      renderEditCell: (params: GridRenderEditCellParams) => {
        // How to get the options here ? 
       // valueOptions = ???
        return (
          <Autocomplete
            disablePortal
            options={valueOptions}
            sx={{ width: params.colDef.width }}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Type" />}
          />
        )
      }
    },
```